# Different % of CPU usage of two equivalent run of a OpenMP program on same cluster node

Tags: c++, openmp, cluster-computing, slurm, icc

[image: Snapshot of top command]

A **C++ OpenMP** program compiled with intel compiler is submitted on a cluster node using **SLURM** job scheduler with **two different parameters** on two different directories. The number of threads is **20** for each. But one program is running with **1700-2000%CPU** (which is ok) and the other is running with **500-950%CPU**, almost one-third or half of the first one. What is causing this kind of performance difference? The same thing happens when the program runs on different nodes of the same configuration. Here is the part of the code where OpenMP is used.

```cpp
#define NUMBER_OF_THREADS 20
...
...
void someFunction(){
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NUMBER_OF_THREADS) collapse(2)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NX; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < NY; j++) {
            // work to be done

        }
    }

}
```

Here is the SLURM job submission script,

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -J name               
#SBATCH -p partitionName
#SBATCH -n 1                       # no of processes
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=20

module load compiler/intel/2019.5.281

cd my_working_directory
path_of_the_executable
```

Here is the node details

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                40
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-39
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    20
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 85
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6148 CPU @ 2.40GHz
```

Comment: Experience show that the problem is often in the `work to be done` you did not provide. If there is a lock or system calls or anything like this, then this is a normal behaviour. It is hard as a user to know that since even memory accesses can cause hidden system calls (inter-process/device shared memory, page faults, etc.). Over-subscription of BLAS is also a frequent issue. This is impossible to tell with the current description. Besides, did you check the threads correctly pinned to cores?

Comment: Here, I am doing basic calculations like addition, subtraction, sin, cos, exp on the elements of  flatten vectors and not using BLAS. If both the run would show the same but lower CPU usage, then it is obviously the problem of `work to be done` part , but here that was not the case.

Comment: Ok and what about the thread pinning? There is a high chance this is related to that.  There are memory accesses isn't it? If so the balancing can be (and often is) dependent of the NUMA page placement and the imbalance due to due to the default allocation policy (especially if hyper-threads are used which is not clear). You can check if the problem does not comes from this by removing any memory accesses in the parallel loop (at least all that are non local). You can also tweak the NUMA policy.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62604334/how-do-numactl-perf-change-memory-placement-policy-of-child-processes/62615032#62615032) about `numactl` and the binding od threads may help. By the way, the default Linux scheduler is known no to be reliable when it comes to schedule thread properly on HPC machines. Consider reading [The Linux Scheduler: a Decade of Wasted Cores](https://people.ece.ubc.ca/sasha/papers/eurosys16-final29.pdf). SLURM and the Intel OpenMP runtimes should automatically pin threads to cores but it sometimes fail due to bugs on some HPC machines.

Comment: Please provide the sample reproducer code and steps you have followed to reproduce the issue at our end?