# How to multiply two arrays at specific indexes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication, elementwise-operations

**Toy example**

I have two arrays, which have different shape, for example:

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.arange(5*6*7*8).reshape(5, 6, 7, 8)
vector = np.arange(1, 20, 2)
```

What I want to do is to multiply each element of the matrix by one of the element of 'vector' and then do the sum over the last two axis. For that, I have an array with the same shape as 'matrix' that tells me which index to use, for example:

```
Idx = (matrix+np.random.randint(0, vector.size, size=matrix.shape))%vector.size
```

I know that one of the solution would be to do:

```
matVec = vector[Idx]
res = np.sum(matrix*matVec, axis=(2, 3))
```

or even:

```
res = np.einsum('ijkl, ijkl -> ij', matrix, matVec)
```

**Problem**

However, my problems is that my arrays are big and the construction of matVec takes both times and memory. So is there a way to bypass that and still achieve the same result ?

**More realistic example**

Here is a more realistic example of what I'm actually doing:

```
import numpy as np

order = 20
dim = 23

listOrder = np.arange(-order, order+1, 1)
N, P = np.meshgrid(listOrder, listOrder)
K = np.arange(-2*dim+1, 2*dim+1, 1)
X = np.arange(-2*dim, 2*dim, 1)

tN = np.einsum('..., p, x -> ...px', N, np.ones(K.shape, dtype=int), np.ones(X.shape, dtype=int))#, optimize=pathInt)
tP = np.einsum('..., p, x -> ...px', P, np.ones(K.shape, dtype=int), np.ones(X.shape, dtype=int))#, optimize=pathInt)
tK = np.einsum('..., p, x -> ...px', np.ones(P.shape, dtype=int), K, np.ones(X.shape, dtype=int))#, optimize=pathInt)
tX = np.einsum('..., p, x -> ...px', np.ones(P.shape, dtype=int), np.ones(K.shape, dtype=int), X)#, optimize=pathInt)
tL = tK + tX

mini, maxi = -4*dim+1, 4*dim-1
NmPp2L = np.arange(2*mini-2*order, 2*maxi+2*order+1)
Idx = (2*tL+tN-tP) - NmPp2L[0]

np.random.seed(0)
matrix = (np.random.rand(Idx.size) + 1j*np.random.rand(Idx.size)).reshape(Idx.shape)
vector = np.random.rand(np.max(Idx)+1) + 1j*np.random.rand(np.max(Idx)+1)

res = np.sum(matrix*vector[Idx], axis=(2, 3))
```

Comment: I think operation vector[Idx] should not take considerable time unless your memory is full.

Comment: The thing is I do this operation a number of times which as a all takes times. I made a test which ran for 100s, from which 10s where used only for this operation. Also, for the moment memory is not a problem, but it will become at some points and that is also why I would like to avoid this operation as it creates a large array

Comment: How big are values in practice? If `Idx` is very random and `vector` is very large, then memory accesses can be pretty slow. I doubt the provided code can be an issue. Please update it to reflect the actual problem you have on your machine (so to make it *reproducible*).

Comment: @Okapi575 I beg to differ. Since that is [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), it will create a copy of the original array, and for sufficiently large inputs, this can be a decent contributor to the overall time.

Answer (score 5):

For larger data arrays

```py
import numpy as np

matrix = np.arange(50*60*70*80).reshape(50, 60, 70, 80)
vector = np.arange(1, 50, 2)
Idx = (matrix+np.random.randint(0, vector.size, size=matrix.shape))%vector.size
```

parallel `numba` speeds up the computation and avoids creating *matVec*.

On a 4-core Intel Xeon Platinum 8259CL

```py
matVec = vector[Idx]
# %timeit 48.4 ms ± 167 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

res = np.einsum('ijkl, ijkl -> ij', matrix, matVec)
# %timeit 26.9 ms ± 40.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

against an unoptimized `numba` implementation

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def func(matrix, idx, vector):
    res = np.zeros((matrix.shape[0],matrix.shape[1]), dtype=matrix.dtype)
    for i in nb.prange(matrix.shape[0]):
        for j in range(matrix.shape[1]):
            for k in range(matrix.shape[2]):
                for l in range(matrix.shape[3]):
                    res[i,j] += matrix[i,j,k,l] * vector[idx[i,j,k,l]]
    return res

func(matrix, Idx, vector)  # compile run
func(matrix, Idx, vector)
# %timeit 21.7 ms ± 486 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# (48.4 + 26.9) / 21.7 = ~3.47x speed up

np.testing.assert_equal(func(matrix, Idx, vector), np.einsum('ijkl, ijkl -> ij', matrix, matVec))
```

---

### Performance and further optimizations

The above Numba code should be **memory-bound** when dealing with complex numbers. Indeed, `matrix` and `Idx` are big and must be completely read from the relatively-slow RAM. `matrix` has a size of `41*41*92*92*8*2 = 217.10 MiB` and `Idx` a size of either `41*41*92*92*8 = 108.55 MiB` or `41*41*92*92*4 = 54.28 MiB` regarding the target platform (it should be of type int32 on most x86-64 Windows platforms and int64 on most Linux x86-64 platforms). This is also why `vector[Idx]` was slow: Numpy needs to write a big array in memory (not to mention writing data should be twice slower than reading it on x86-64 platforms in this case).

Assuming the code is memory bound, the only way to speed it up is to reduce the amount of data read from the RAM. This can be achieve by storing `Idx` in a `uint16` array instead of the default `np.int_` datatype (2~4 bigger). This is possible since `vector.size` is small. On a Linux with a i5-9600KF processor and a 38-40 GiB/s RAM, this optimization resulted in a ~29% speed up while the code is still mainly memory bound. The implementation is nearly optimal on this platform.

Comment: What would you do to optimize the `numba` implementation?

Comment: @norok2 -I suppose you could try triggering compilation with avx calls for the trailing axis. But that almost never works for me. I usually only implement the trivial (parallel) loop solution.

Comment: Good implementation! I added a note so to speed it up. One should care about the NUMA policy on computing servers as the default policy is generally to allocate pages locally on first touch. Since Numpy fill arrays mostly serially, the Numba code will use the RAM of only 1 NUMA node while computing servers generally have multiple NUMA nodes. `numactl --interleaved=XXX` can be used to mitigate this problem (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62604334)) where `XXX` can be `0,1` for a platform with 2 NUMA ndoes (see `numactl --show`).